# Map/Reduce on Scoped collection with Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am trying to map/reduce a scope in a Rails 3.1 app using MongoDB with Mongoid.

The results seem odd, so I wonder if map_reduce can be applied on a prescoped collection for example like that:

```
current_user.tasks.for_year_and_month(year, month).collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :out => "res")
```

for_year_and_month scopes tasks on a given month, but the results from map_reduce seem to include other tasks too. Now I wonder whether my map/reduce functions are wrong, or map/reduce can not be applied on pre-scoped collections.

If so, I had to do all the scope's work in my emit function what would make things even worse. I can't believe that.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 0):

The scope is ignored because you're working directly on collection.

You can pass the :query option to map_reduce and this will filter documents.

Eg:

```
Task.collection.map_reduce(map,reduce,out:{merge:'res'},query:{user_id: x, ...})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're after:

```
results = Task.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, {query: {month: month, year: year}, out: "reduced_task_results"})
filtered_results = results.find({})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scope selector from Mongoid in the query option:

```
scoped = current_user.tasks.whatever
Task.map_reduce( ..., :query => scoped.selector)
```